# Dictionary is not convertible to Void

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Hi guys I've been searching the net without much luck but I'm trying to get around Alamofires asynchronous nature. I'm trying to return the JSON response as a dictionary but Xcode is giving me "Dictionary is not convertible to 'Void'"

```
func homePageDetails(userName:String) -> (Dictionary<String,AnyObject>){
    let username = userName
    let hompePageDetails = Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://example.com/API/Bunch/GetHomePageDetails/\(username)/").responseJSON{(request, response, JSON, error) in
    print(JSON)
    var test = JSON as Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
    return test
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: were you able to make alamofire return an object back?

Comment: Yeah I was. You have to use callbacks and it works fine. The answer below is correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are returning `test: Dictionary<String,AnyObject>` from closure and not from `homePageDetails` method. Closure return type is `Void`, thats why you get this error.

I haven't used Alamofire myself, but `Alamofire.request` seems like non-blocking call. If its so you cannot return from this function. You can use something like completion closure. Non tested concept:

```
func homePageDetails(userName:String, completion:(Dictionary<String,AnyObject>) -> Void) {
    let username = userName
    let hompePageDetails = Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://example.com/API/Bunch/GetHomePageDetails/\(username)/").responseJSON{(request, response, JSON, error) in
        print(JSON)
        var test = JSON as Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
        completion(test)
    }
}
```