# How to use closures to return a JSON value from a NSURLSession

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to return a result from a JSON object but unable to do so. I am new to Swift so kindly explain me how to do so. In the below code I want to return `json_level_number` in the return of function `fetchNumberOfSections ()` where i have hard coded as 5 right now `return 5`. If i declare a variable `json_level_number` just above the reachability code it sort of solves the problem but then it is returning '0' for the first time. The API returns 2 each time.

Code as below:

```
func fetchNumberOfSections () -> Int {
    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
        // Below code to fetch number of sections 
        var urlAsString = "http://themostplayed.com/rest/fetch_challenge_sections.php"
        urlAsString = urlAsString+"?apiKey="+apiKey
        print (urlAsString)
        let url = NSURL(string: urlAsString)!
        let urlSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let jsonQuery = urlSession.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
            do {
                let jsonResult = (try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary
                let json_level_number: String! = jsonResult["level_number"] as! String
                //
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    //                self.dateLabel.text = jsonDate
                    //                self.timeLabel.text = jsonTime
                    print(json_level_number)  
               //     self.activityIndicatorStop()
                })
            }
            catch let errorJSON {
                print (errorJSON)
                // alert box code below
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "JSON Error!", message:"Error processing JSON.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in
                    // Put here any code that you would like to execute when
                    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})
                }
                alert.addAction(action)
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                // alert box code end
            }
        })
        jsonQuery.resume()
        // End
    }
    else {
        print("Internet connection FAILED")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("nointernet", sender: nil)
    }
    return 5
}
```

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31608302/return-value-from-completion-handler-swift/31608684#31608684

Comment: Another example: [returning a value from a function with Alamofire and SwiftyJson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30771881/returning-a-value-from-a-function-with-alamofire-and-swiftyjson)

Comment: Nop, Still not able to solve my concern. Can you explain in a better way how should i pass `json_level_number` in the return of my `fetchNumberOfSections` function.

Comment: I am using the `fetchNumberOfSections` as the number of sections for a `UITableView` I am not able to pass the correct value