# Swift - Returning a JSON object from API call in Model as Dictionary to use in View Controller

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary

I have recently started experimenting with Swift and am new to more strongly typed programming languages.

I am trying to build a basic API call to http://openweathermap.org/api which will have a searchbox in the UIView that takes a city name and returns the relevant weather data.

My problem is figuring out how to return the JSON response I get back from my API call in my Model as a Dictionary that I can then use as a variable in my ViewController.

I have experimented with a variety of methods but continue to get a 'Dictionary not convertible to Void' error. From research and this article ([Dictionary is not convertible to Void](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26118556/dictionary-is-not-convertible-to-void)) it seems returning a closure might offer the answer but I am struggling to implement given that I only want to pass a cityname string parameter in my ViewController searchButton function.

Detailed code snippets below, thanks for help!

My API call in Model below which currently works at pulling down JSON object

```
class API {
func weatherSearch(#urlSearch: String) -> Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
{
    let urlPath = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + urlSearch
    let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        println("Task completed")
        if(error != nil) {
            // If there is an error in the web request, print it to the console
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        var err: NSError?
        if let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary {
            var dataOut = jsonResult as Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
            return dataOut
         //omitted some additional error handling code
        }
    })
    task.resume()
 }
}
```

My ViewController where instantiate API and take input from Searchfield

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchField: UITextField!

@IBAction func searchButton() {
    let api = API()
    var dataOut = api.weatherSearch(urlSearch: searchField.text!)
    println(dataOut)
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Search", sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: Your function will never work. The data is requested asynchronously but your function is not prepared for that. Add a completion block to the function like the data task does.

Comment: @HorseT: are you referring to something along the lines of this? 
         `if let results: NSArray = jsonResult["results"] as? NSArray {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        println(results)
                    })
             }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the callback technique as hinted to by the comment above, try something like this

```
func weatherSearch(#urlSearch: String, callback: (Dictionary<String,AnyObject> -> ())) {
    let urlPath = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + urlSearch
    let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        println("Task completed")
        if(error != nil) {
            // If there is an error in the web request, print it to the console
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        var err: NSError?
        if let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary {
            var dataOut = jsonResult as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
            callback(dataOut)
            //omitted some additional error handling code
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}

weatherSearch(urlSearch: "endpoint here") { dictionary in
    println(dictionary)
}
```